# Can I view Git commit history in Visual Studio 2013 for TFS Git VC before cloning?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I have a Git-based TFS Team Project.  I have created additional Git repositories in this Team Project with names other than that of the Team Project.  Prior to cloning the repo, I would like to view its full commit history in VS2013.  I could not figure out how to do so without first cloning the entire repository.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not currently possible to view the history of a remote Git repository from within Visual Studio.

You will need to either:

1. Clone the repository locally, then view the history in Visual Studio; or
2. View the history inside the TFS Web Access interface.

Comment: Thanks, Edward.  I was afraid of that.  :-)  I'm guessing you can't comment, but is this planned for the future?

Comment: Probably not planned for the immediate future, I'm afraid.  It's something that we think would be cool, but there are some prerequisites that we're working on (finalizing our Git REST API) and there are some other features that we want to implement first.

Comment: How does one "view the history in Visual Studio" of a local repo?  I can't find the project history / git log in the Team Explorer.

Comment: @kdbanman I think there are a couple of entry points, but the way I always do it is Team Explorer > Branches, then select the branch I'm on and "View History".

Comment: Wow that was fast.  Thank you!